# Cox Regression Hazard Ratio in Percentiles

Tags: r, percentile, cox-regression

I computed a Cox proportional hazards regression in R.

```
cox.model <- coxph(Surv(time, dead) ~ A + B + C + X, data = df)
```

Now, I got the hazard ratio (HR, or exp(coef)) for all these covariates, but I'm really only interested in the effects of continuous predictor X. The HR for X is 1.20. X is actually scaled to the sample measurements, such that X has a mean of 0 and SD 1. That is, an individual with a 1 SD increase in X has a 1.23 times higher chance of mortality (the event) than someone with an average value of X (I believe).

I would like to be able to say these results in something that's a bit less awkward, and actually [this article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3366177/) does exactly what I would like to. It says:

> "In a Cox proportional hazards model adjusting for age, sex and
> education, a higher level of total daily physical activity was
> associated with a decreased risk of death (hazard ratio=0.71;
> 95%CI:0.63, 0.79). **Thus, an individual with high total daily physical
> activity (90th percentile) had about ¼ the risk of death as compared
> to an individual with low total daily physical activity (10th
> percentile).**"

Assuming only the HR (i.e. 1.20) is needed, how does one compute this comparison statement? If you need any other information, please ask me for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have x1 as your 90th percentile X value and x2 as your 10th percentile X value, and if p,q,r and s (s is1.20 as you have mentioned) and your coefficients of cox regression you need to find `exp(p*A + q*B + r*C + s*x1)/exp(p*A + q*B + r*C + s*x2)` where A, B, and C can be average values of the variable. This ratio give you the comparison statement.

This question is actually for stats.stackexchange.com though.

Comment: Ah, thank you!
I will post my question on stats.stackexchange.com.